# How to call method of another class from this class ?

Tags: c#, class, delegates

I have a Form with a **TextBox** and an **OK button**.I have another class (named AnotherClass) which gets instantiated before the Form class.I am creating a new instance of the Form class in AnotherClass , showing the form to the user and accepting some double value in the textbox. Upon click of the OK button I want to call a method in **AnotherClass** which uses the textbox's text as an argument.How should I do it? Please help.

Comment: Very unclear explanation.

Comment: If I understood right: Create a public method in `AnotherClass` with a parameter (`public void MyMethod(string txtBoxText){ }`) which gets called by the click event

Comment: +1 for being naive. But try onwards, to explain your questions properly and with a piece of code

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you have a winform situation and you want to access textbox value or textbox in your another class.

If it is so then,

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    public void YourMethodThatAccessTextBox(TextBox t)
    {
            // do something interesting with t;
    }
}

In your OK button

ok_click
{
   AnotherClass ac = new AnotherClass().YourMethodThatAccessTextBox(txtValue);
}
```

Comment: I guess he only wants the value not the TextBox itself

Comment: The Problem is, that the you create a new object of AnotherClass. I guess that's not what he wants

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to solve this

**First one:**

In FormClass:

```
public string txt { get; set; } //A so called property
private void OK_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt = textBox.Text;
    this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();
}
```

In AnotherClass:

```
private void openForm() //Method in AnotherClass where you create your object of your FormClass
{
   FormClass fc = new FormClass ();
   if (fc.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
   {
      YourMethodInAnotherClass(fc.txt);
   }
}
```

**Second Solution (using a parameter):**

In FormClass:

```
AnotherClass anotherClass = null;
public FormClass(AnotherClass a) //Constructor with parameter (object of your AnotherClass)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    anotherClass = a;
}

private void OK_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    anotherClass.YourMethodInAnotherClass(textBox.Text);
    this.Close();
}
```

In AnotherClass:

```
private void openForm()
{
    FormClass fc = new FormClass(this);
    fc.ShowDialog();
}

public void YourMethodInAnotherClass(string txt)
{
    //Do you work
}
```